# Trying to search a variable into 2 different column in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, select, where-clause, pyqt5

Sqlite3 pyqt5 and python3

```
inpsearch = ('%'+self.lineEdit.text()+'%',)
conn = sqlite3.connect('formuladatabase')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS search')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE search(rowid, Name TEXT, Surname TEXT, datestamp TEXT, Stylist TEXT, formula TEXT, Price REAL)')
```

that was the original below which work

```
#c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name LIKE ?', inpsearch)
```

one column work great , but im looking to search through 2 columns

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name=? OR Surname=?', inpsearch, inpsearch)
```

this return : Type error function take at most 2 arguments (3) given

```
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

looking to fix that for days... also a side question do anybody know how to make a auto-complete (.setCompleter) for QlineEdit with Pyqt5

thank you

Comment: Try `c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name=? OR Surname=?', [inpsearch, inpsearch])`?

Comment: i get : sqlite3.interfaceerror: error binding parameter 0 probably unsuported type .

Comment: Suggests something wrong with **inpsearch**. When I use these statements: `Name='Bill'
Surname='Bell'
c.execute('INSERT INTO search (Name, Surname) values (?,?)', [Name, Surname])` they succeed. I suggest you print out **inpsearch**.

Comment: inpsearch work with c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name LIKE ?', inpsearch) you only have 2 arguments in yours this is why it works . try with 3

Comment: You may not have noticed that my SQL is not quite the same as yours, because I don't have your database. I've just tried `Name='Bill'
Surname='Bell'
Stylist='Rembrandt'
c.execute('INSERT INTO search (Name, Surname,Stylist) values (?,?,?)', [Name, Surname,Stylist])` — with success. I actually looked at the database record created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` needs 2 arguments, the sql-statement and a tuple of parameters (in Your case 2 bindvalues). You provide the sql-statement and 2 tuples with 1 parameter.

this should work:

```
bv = '%'+self.lineEdit.text()+'%'
inpsearch = (bv, bv, )
c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name=? OR Surname=?', inpsearch)
```

or alternatively:

```
inpsearch = ('%'+self.lineEdit.text()+'%',)
c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name= {0} OR Surname= {0}', inpsearch)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this helped Greatly Here is my final solution bv = '%'+self.lineEdit.text()+'%'
            inpsearch = (bv, bv, )
            c.execute('INSERT INTO search SELECT * FROM clientsformula WHERE Name LIKE ? OR Surname LIKE ?', inpsearch)